# TWIG and "unexpected T_FUNCTION" which return a server 500 error with hostmonster.com

Tags: twig

I have this code which works on my localhost and with one.com web hosting. But when uploaded in hostmonster.com's ftp, the browser return a 500 error. 
I'm using TWIG as template engine.

Here are the link to the pages:

- doesn't work(hostmonster.com): http://armourertech.com/produit.php
- work(one.com): http://chacartz.fr/autre/armourer/produit.php

The technician at hostmonster.com told me the error is on the line 12:

`$walkdir_gearbox = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_gearbox', function ($path_01)`

Code:

```
<?php 

require "twig.php";
require "nav.php";
$head_title = "armourertech";
$nav['produit'] = "actuel";
$keywords = "";
$description = "";
$robots = "index, follow";
$googlebot = "index, follow";


$walkdir_gearbox = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_gearbox', function ($path_01) {//<-line 12
    $path_01 = "img/x-hightech/01gearbox";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_01);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/01gearbox/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/01gearbox/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_gearbox($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$walkdir_gearboxcnc = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_gearboxcnc', function ($path_02) {
    $path_02 = "img/x-hightech/02fabrication-gearbox-cnc";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_02);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/02fabrication-gearbox-cnc/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/02fabrication-gearbox-cnc/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_gearboxcnc($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$walkdir_piston = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_piston', function ($path_03) {
    $path_03 = "img/x-hightech/03piston-gear-set";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_03);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/03piston-gear-set/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/03piston-gear-set/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_piston($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$walkdir_cylindre = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_cylindre', function ($path_04) {
    $path_04 = "img/x-hightech/04tete-cylindre";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_04);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/04tete-cylindre/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/04tete-cylindre/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_cylindre($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$walkdir_hopup = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_hopup', function ($path_05) {
    $path_05 = "img/x-hightech/05hopup";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_05);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/05hopup/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/05hopup/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_hopup($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$walkdir_autre = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_autre', function ($path_06) {
    $path_06 = "img/x-hightech/06autres";
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($path_06);
    foreach($d as $f)  {
        if(
            preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())
        ) {
           list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            $file = basename($f, ".jpg");
            echo "<figure itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\"><a href=\"img/x-hightech/06autres/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"".$w."x".$h."\"><img src=\"img/x-hightech/thumbs/06autres/".$f->getFilename() . "\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" alt=\"".$file." - ARMOURERTECH\" /></a><figcaption itemprop=\"caption description\">".$file."</figcaption></figure>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkdir_autre($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
});

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_gearbox);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_gearboxcnc);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_piston);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_cylindre);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_hopup);
$twig->addFilter($walkdir_autre);
echo $twig->render('produit.html', array(
    'nav' => $nav,
    'head_title' => $head_title,
    'keywords' => $keywords,
    'description' => $description,
    'robots' => $robots,
    'googlebot' => $googlebot
    )
);

?>
```

then I put this line in the html:

```
{{ 'twig' |walkdir_gearbox }}
```

Here are the last lines of the error.log file

```
[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: magickwand: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so: undefined symbol: zend_ini_string_ex in Unknown on line 0

[15-Dec-2015 03:15:45] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home8/armourer/public_html/produit.php on line 12
```

Is there a solution or am I forced to change provider?

Comment: First of all, the line `preg_match("/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/", $f->getFilename())` doesn't end with a `;`.

Comment: if i add a `;` the browser return: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\armourer\produit.php on line 17

Comment: or: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\wamp\www\armourer\produit.php on line 22

Comment: What about this line: `preg_match('/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/', $f->getFilename())`

Comment: The only difference is using simple quotes to avoid problems with `$`.

Comment: But the error is pointed on the line : `$walkdir_gearbox = new Twig_SimpleFilter ( 'walkdir_gearbox', function ($path_01)` and only on hosmonster.com. And i did this `'`change but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "()" on the last line, it should read:

```
echo $twig->render('produit.html');
```

Also, check the PHP version: anonymous functions as parameters are allowed only on PHP 5.3.0 and above.

Comment: I have edited my post and puted the full code. Here is the end: `echo $twig->render('produit.html', array(
    'nav' => $nav,
    'head_title' => $head_title,
    'keywords' => $keywords,
    'description' => $description,
    'robots' => $robots,
    'googlebot' => $googlebot
    )
);`

Comment: Have you checked the php version?

Comment: DAMN!!! the .htaccess say it's the 5.4! but when i check it it say it's the PHP Version 5.2.17 !!! The technician said some bullshit :'x i have to contact them one more time u_u' . probleme solved, it was the php version. now it work :> thank you all

Comment: check my answer as correct, please do it! it's my first! :-)